# Questions about Enums in Java

Tags: java, enums

How can I say something like:

```
 System.out.println(Enum.ATESTSTRING + " is a test string!");
```

and not:

```
 System.out.println(Enum.ATESTSTRING.getString() + " is a test string!");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `toString()` method in your `enum`:

```
enum MyEnum {
    ATESTSTRING("A test String");

    private final String value;

    MyEnum(String value) { this.value = value; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {return value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will give best answer when I can!

Comment: If you are returning the literal enum every time then it is better to use the default options built into the Enum class (the default `toString()` or `name()`) rather than adding a private attribute and overriding `toString()` every time.

Comment: @mdl Yeah that's right. But with this approach OP can put any value he/she wants for `value`. I've just put it like this for illustration.

Answer (score 1):

`Enum.ATESTSTRING.toString()` or `Enum.ATESTSTRING.name()` (if you want to use your `toString()` for something else).

The `name()` method belongs to [the Enum class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), so all enum values automatically have this method available.

Answer (score 0):

By default [Enum#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString%28%29) will return its name. You should be able to just do your first expression. The String concatenation (+ operator) will call toString automatically.

```
enum TestEnum {
    ATESTSTRING;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ATESTSTRING + " is a test string");
    }
}
```

Will output `ATESTSTRING is a test string`.